# Google Sheet - matching first and last names

Tags: google-sheets, matching

On my Google sheet, I want to print the ID# matching associated with a first and last name of a member.   One section of my Google sheet has rows with matching
first name, last name, and ID#s.  Another subsection of this sheet has First name and Last name.

This is what I have done so far. It works for Last names.

```
=IFNA(INDEX($AC:$AC,MATCH($F2,$AA:$AA,0)))
```

Columns descriptions
First section:

A  -   ID# ,
D   -  First Name ,
F   -  Last name ,

second section of sheet (A subset of first section):

Z   -  First name ,
AA  -  Last name ,
AC  -  ID#  ?

Comment: Use the `FILTER` function

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be probably to make a column that combines First and Last name into one cell in both tables, so that you can use either IFNA-formula or a Vlookup.

Also, you can combine two criterias with "&". I tested the code below in google spreadsheets, should work.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($AC:$AC,MATCH($D2&$F2,$Z:$Z&$AA:$AA,0),1),0)
```

[Check me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKAbU.png)